# trying to get 1 class from an element that has two in jQuery

Tags: jquery, class

I want to target an element that has two class names set on it:

ex.

```
<li style="display:none;" class="productList product-1">
    <p class="removeIcon"><img src="images/remove-icon.jpg" align="Remove Product" /></p>
    <span class="companyName">Company 1 goes here and here is a test for two lines</span>
</li>
```

When i try to get the class of the li in jQuery:

```
var parent = $(this).parent().get(0).className();
```

it returns "productList product-1" i want to be able to return or reduce the output to be just: "product-1". I know this is probably pretty easy, but i don't know of a way right now.

I need it to be in that order of class defining too. Another function is using the "productList" part...

I would be ok with just removing the first part if there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.parentNode.className.split(' ')[1];
```

or with jQuery:

```
$(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ')[1];
```

but I'd prefer the first.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to target an element that has
>   two class names set on it

```
if($(this).hasClass('firstOne') && $(this).hasClass('secondOne')) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ')[1];
```

This should do the job for you!

Answer (score 0):

Not an *answer* to your question, per sé, but an alternative: [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

While it's very common to use classes for this type of data storage, they're sub-optimal, in no small part due to having to parse the data back out, as you've seen.  Recent versions of jQuery, however, support HTML5-style ["data attributes"](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) which do the same job much better.  (And *do* work with HTML4 and XHTML, though you'll get validation errors.)

To use them, change your HTML to something like:

```
<li style="display:none;" class="productList" data-product="1">
    <p class="removeIcon"><img src="images/remove-icon.jpg" align="Remove Product" /></p>
    <span class="companyName">Company 1 goes here and here is a test for two lines</span>
</li>
```

In jQuery, you can then use `.data()`:

```
var parent = $(this).parent().get(0).data("product"); // parent === 1
```

(Note that the `"1"` in your HTML gets automagically converted from a string to a number.)